# "undefined reference to `CreateStreamOnHGlobal@12'" error faced on executing gdiplus c++ code

Tags: c++, gdi+

i found [a code on github](https://gist.github.com/prashanthrajagopal/05f8ad157ece964d8c4d) which takes a screenshot and saves it as a jpeg file. I copied and pasted it in notepad++, saved it, and compiled it with the following command:

```
g++ -mwindows screenshot.cpp -lgdiplus
```

and faced the following error:

```
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTLI53G.o:screenshot.cpp:(.text+0x158): undefined reference to `CreateStreamOnHGlobal@12'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

it seems to be this line which is causing the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#include <time.h>
//stuff....
HRESULT res = CreateStreamOnHGlobal(NULL, true, &istream);// this line (line 38)
//stuff....
```

*Any help as to why the code is not working will be highly appreciated...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this site:

[CreateStreamOnHGlobal function (combaseapi.h) - Win32 apps | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-createstreamonhglobal)

The library that contains `CreateStreamOnHGlobal` function is `Ole32.lib`, so `-lole32` should be added to the command line.